# FTP user that can browse all home subfolders

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, ssh, ftp

I'm new to servers...

I have disabled root login via SSH for security reasons.

I have created a 'user' but that user can only browse his own /home/user folder via FTP.

If I want to be able to control all /home subfolders (directories from all the other users) via FTP, I need to login as the root...

Is there any way to grant 'user' with privileges to be able to browse, edit and create files and folders via FTP to all subfolders in the /home directory?

If that is not a good idea please explain.

Comment: There is no mention of Ubuntu or a Ubuntu version in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, need to install ACL and use the command

```
setfacl -R -m u:someuser:rwX /home
```

Answers can be found [here](https://programmer.iz.rs/allow-user-to-rwx-permissions-to-home-folder/)